# combobox in django?

Tags: django, drop-down-menu

What's the simplest way to create an editable dropdown in django, i.e a dropdown list that I can also edit as though it's a textarea?

Is there something that's close to plug-and-play, or do I need to write a lot of gritty code?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like a Combobox? I don't know if such a thing exists in the browser. Perhaps it can be done with some Javascript. Google around is my best suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, I meant a combobox. Changed the question's title.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way appears to be to use an existing javascript library to create a combobox (for instance [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html)) and create a widget that uses that library as it's media.